# How can i do an equivalent JS for in vue? (Increments in n numbers)

Tags: vue.js, for-loop, v-for

i'm trying to make a select with numbers skipped by 15 units (It's a select of minutes: 0 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 minutes, 45 minutes), i've made it using EJS:

```
<% for(let x = 0; x < 60; x+= 15) { %>
   <option value="<%= x %>"><%= x %> minutes</option>
<% } %>
```

It works in EJS, but now i'm migrating that component to a Vue 3 component, but i don't know how can i do a for like that, that for is skipping by 15 units, in vue i just can use a for skipping 1 unit:

```
<option v-for="i in 60" :key="i" :value="i">{{ i }} minutes</option>
```

So how can i "translate" that EJS code to Vue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Commentary

Because this only has 4 possible values, I would probably just hard-code them in a util library and import them into the components I needed them

#### Solution

I'd use a computed property to handle this:

```js
new Vue({
  computed: {
    timeIntervals() {
      let time = 0;
      let ret = [];

      while (time < 60) {
        ret.push(time);
        time += 15;
      }

      return ret;
    }
  },
}).$mount('#root');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <select>
    <option v-for="interval in timeIntervals" :key="interval" :value="interval">{{interval}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I generate the intervals array in the computed property, and then use that inside of the template to display each interval

#### Solution w/ Vue 3

```js
const App = {
  computed: {
    timeIntervals() {
      let intervals = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < 60; i += 15) {
        intervals.push(i);
      }

      return intervals;
    },
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#root')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>


<div id="root">
  <select>
    <option v-for="interval in timeIntervals" :key="interval" :value="interval">{{interval}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd love to know _why_ this was downvoted since it gives the correct answer

Comment: there you have an upvote just to level things out, maybe just edit the answer to show a `<select>` with `<options>` instead of just divs

Comment: strange,yeah no idea. It does help answer the question

Comment: Nice! I think this is a good alternative, i was trying to made it in a native way but it seems to be Vue doesn't support a for like this, but made a property who has the for result is a good alternative, also i was thinking in use render functions with JSX, but i don't know if in JSX i can use the native JS for, anyway, thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the Modulo operator  which will return true or false  based  on a divisional outcome

```
<option v-for="i in 60" v-if="i % 15 == true">{{ i - 1 }} minutes</option>
```

This loop will through each value 1...60 and divide it by 15 only printing the result if it's true.

It's commonly bad practice to use v-for and v-if at the same time, but this will get you where you want to be.

**outcome:**

```
0 minutes
15 minutes
30 minutes
45 minutes
```

Comment: this would loop 60 times even though you only need 4 values

Comment: The performance is not in question.  I just gave him the vue equivalent which is what was asked for

Comment: This is not the equivalent; his answer only loops through 4 values